# Running long JPA tasks over a faily VPN

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Is there a way to keep a JPA EntityManagerFactory alive across connection loss and restart? I am trying to run an hours-long task that requires occasional minutes-long database operations (I'm using JPA) over a VPN that doesn't stay up for hours.

Comment: Probably StackOverflow is not the best place to ask this question. I networking StachExhchange community would probably be best.

Comment: Write the result of the query in a result table. Then you just have to make a simple SELECT on that table when you come back later.